# Starting "Choose Profiles" window for Google Chrome through Command Line?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line-arguments

I am maintaining a good number of Google accounts for a research project, and I would like to open the following window quickly. I have looked up the following documentation, and did not find a proper flag to start such "Manage People" window:

- [A list of useful Google Chrome command line switches](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/list-useful-google-chrome-command-line-switches/)
- [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Lastly, I am happy to switch to a certain distribution of Chromium browser if it gets me to quickly switch between "profiles".

[image]

Comment: I am super incapable of using the mouse and would like to avoid the mental pressure of finding the tiny icon for the current user, and then to look for the Manage People menu item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured this one out...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Guest Profile"
```

Comment: As an update to this: 

You can also edit the JSON file %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State 

And add in "show_picker_on_startup": true 

Which is located under the "profile" section. 

When editing 'Local State' make sure you completely close Chrome first (no running processes in the Task Manager), and make sure you keep the JSON valid by using a formatter/validator!